# Where is backpropagation performed in this example

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, data-science, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I have an example of DNN learning XOR (right click to open in new tab): https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1M5xFp4gaXPCbnejM8-5_yLp1B6UvwdL8

I'm confused in these 2 lines (related to backpropagation):

```
Grads = T.gradient(Loss,[W1,B1,W2,B2]);
Optim.apply_gradients(zip(Grads,[W1,B1,W2,B2]));
```

I'm guessing the backward loop is at `T.gradient` because those are gradient values related to loss, but I'm still not clear. The questions are:

- Question1. Is there backpropagation (the backward loop) in those 2 lines?
- Question2. If there is backpropagation, it's at `T.gradient` or `Optim.apply_gradients`?
- Question3. Because backpropagation is done backward, is the order of `[W1,B1,W2,B2]` important? I believe, eg. this shuffled `[B1,W2,B2,W1]` can't be the same, because backpropagation needs layer order from output back to input.

From my trying, when shuffling the order of weights and biases in the variable array, the optimisation process is still working. **But backpropagation needs layer order from output back to input, I don't get this**.

Source code:

```
#!pip install tensorflow==2.0.0rc2
%tensorflow_version 2.x
%reset -f

#libs
import tensorflow as tf;

#data
X = [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]];
Y = [[0],  [1],  [1],  [0]  ];
X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X,tf.float32);
Y = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y,tf.float32);

#model
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([2,20],-1,1));
B1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([  20],-1,1));

W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([20,1],-1,1));
B2 = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([   1],-1,1));

@tf.function
def feedforward(X):
  H1  = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(X,W1) + B1);
  Out = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(H1,W2) + B2);
  return Out;
#end def

#train
Optim = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(1e-1);
Steps = 1000;

for I in range(Steps):
  if I%(Steps/10)==0:
    Out  = feedforward(X);
    Loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y-Out));
    print("Loss:",Loss.numpy());
  #end if

  with tf.GradientTape() as T:
    Out  = feedforward(X);
    Loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y-Out));
  #end with

  #BACKPROPAGATION HERE?
  Grads = T.gradient(Loss,[W1,B1,W2,B2]);
  Optim.apply_gradients(zip(Grads,[W1,B1,W2,B2]));
#end for

Out  = feedforward(X);
Loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y-Out));
print("Loss:",Loss.numpy(),"(Last)");

print("\nDone.");
#eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TensorFlow 2 in default eager mode, and even without the @tf.function decorator to make graph. TensorFlow is still tracking the relation between tensors while calculation: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/272000/142160

TensorFlow tracks every variables here:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as T:
    Out  = feedforward(X);
    Loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y-Out));
```

It is **automatic differentiation** (kinda Monte Carlo method) instead of mathematical differentiation, and thus, all gradients obtained by the following function is already at their proper depths in backpropagation (just like the backward loop to calculate errors at all layers):

```
Grads = T.gradient(Loss,[W1,B1,W2,B2]);
```

After that, optimiser will apply gradients to change weights and biases:

```
Optim.apply_gradients(zip(Grads,[W1,B1,W2,B2]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take this one step at a time.

Step 1: Calculation of Gradients:

```
Grads = T.gradient(Loss,[W1,B1,W2,B2])
```

Here, we calculate the gradients of the loss with respect to the variables in the provided list. The list of gradients is indexed based on the indices of the variables. This means that `Grads[0]` will be the gradients with respect to `W1`, and so on.

Step 2: Next, we perform the update. This is done in:

```
Optim.apply_gradients(zip(Grads,[W1,B1,W2,B2]))
```

Here, `Grads[0]` are used to update `W1`, `Grads[1]` to update `B1` and so on.

Note that gradient calculation and the update steps are performed separately. So as long as the variables appear in the same order in both lists, there shouldn't be any problems.

Also, `GradientTape` has to be used with Eager Execution.

Comment: i know the variable list is supposed to be the same on those 2 lines, but the main thing is in which line backpropagation is performed

Comment: `Backpropagation` is an algorithm involving multiple steps, starting from calculation of the loss to updation of the variables involved. Both steps mentioned in the questions are parts of the algorithm.

Comment: ok, so there is backpropagation, and the loop of backpropagation is in both lines. But, is the order of [w1,b1,w2,b2] important?

Comment: No, it isn't. All gradients are calculated independently.

Comment: oh, dependently, where's the backward loop then?

Comment: That is implemented internally in `apply_gradients()` method of the optimizer.

Comment: how does `apply_gradients` know which variable is of which layer? to loop from output back to input

Comment: It doesn't have to know. All variables are encapsulated with their gradients when you call `zip(Grads,[W1,B1,W2,B2])`. The gradients are simply applied to their corresponding variables via some update rule, based on the optimizer.

Comment: To understand it better, take a look at the shapes of `Gradients` and `zip(Grads,[W1,B1,W2,B2])`.

Comment: seems u dont get me. Backpropagation must have 1 backward loop from output to last hidden, to second last hidden, .... , to third hidden, to second hidden, to first hidden layer. If it doesn't need to know the order of layers, then it's not backpropagation (question1)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200084/discussion-between-susmit-agrawal-and-datdinhquoc).